# VSCode can't autocomplete laravel and doesn't show all syntax errors

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode with PHP IntelliSense. I also tried PHP Intelephense.

VSCode can't autocomplete things like Eloquent Model, Laravel Helpers etc. For Examle $this->**hasMany()** and a lot of other stuff related to laravel framework. VSCode can autocomplete php standard functions only. Also VSCode doesn't show me type errors like forgotten "**>**", for example $channel->threads()->latest()**-get()**; I lost already many hours with searching different typos. VSCode recognize standard typos only, like fogotten "**;**" "**()**".

Are there any addons I can use to fix this problem? If not, are there other free editors that can autocomplete laravel functions and see typo errors that VSCode doesn't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a complete guide to prepare **VSCode** for Laravel [there](https://medium.com/@ardanirohman/laravel-%EF%B8%8F-visual-studio-code-debug-environment-65440274d3b0).

As a second option I highly recommend you **Sublime Text 3** because is flat, free to download, simple and fast, it have a lot of packages helping you to work with Laravel, like: Laravel 5 Snippets, Laravel Blade Highlighter, Blade Snippets...

Comment: Thank you for the link! This article is very usefull. I didn't know what AddOns I should use with VSCode. Now I know it.

Comment: Sublime Text is NOT free. Please check here: https://www.sublimetext.com/buy?v=3.0

Comment: @SinanEldem Corrected *free* to free to download.

Comment: Recommend Sublime over VS Code is highly unwise.

Answer (score 4):

You can also set **php.suggest.basic** to false to disable VS Code's built-in php code completion and avoid duplicate suggestions.

I found this after accessing Troyer's link and try to install the PHP Intelisense - Crane version.

After read the description (the extensios is out of market) but I have some others installed.

When I set the configuration to false, only the scoped suggestions is showed.

I was looking for this help becaus when I am creating some Blueprint items, the suggestion brings me up all php functions and not those correlated to what I am doing...

Sorry about my english...

P.S. here are my installed extensions:

```
abusaidm.html-snippets
amiralizadeh9480.laravel-extra-intellisense
austenc.laravel-blade-spacer
austenc.laravel-docs
bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client
calebporzio.better-phpunit
christian-kohler.path-intellisense
codingyu.laravel-goto-view
CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer
ctf0.laravel-goto-controller
eamodio.gitlens
ecmel.vscode-html-css
felixfbecker.php-debug
formulahendry.auto-close-tag
humao.rest-client
mikestead.dotenv
ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit
ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack
neilbrayfield.php-docblocker
onecentlin.laravel-blade
onecentlin.laravel5-snippets
patbenatar.advanced-new-file
pflannery.vscode-versionlens
PKief.material-icon-theme
quicktype.quicktype
ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters
sleistner.vscode-fileutils
vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons
```

Comment: this works with current visual studio code version 1.66.2.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the root cause was the Database Client extension. I don't know how to fix it, though.

Comment: It's a comment not an answer